# Will the MAE of testing data always be higher than MAE of training data?

Tags: decision-trees, cross-validation, overfitting

On the [Kaggle Course Page](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/underfitting-and-overfitting) the chart below shows that MAE of testing data is always higher than MAE of training data. Why is this the case? Is it only limited to DecisionTreeRegressor model? Or the graph is wrong and in practice the MAE of testing can be lower than MAE of training?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Train MAE is "generally" lower than Test MAE but not always.

Now coming to your questions.

Q1 Why does this happen?

A1. Train MAE is generally lower than Test MAE because the model has already seen the training set during training. So its easier to score high accuracy on training set. Test set on the other hand is unseen so we generally expect Test MAE to be higher as it more difficult to perform well on unseen data.

However, it is not always necessary for Train MAE to be lower than Test MAE. It might happen "by chance" that the test set is relatively easier (than the training set) for the model to score higher accuracy hence leading to lower Test MAE!

Q2. Is this true only for DecisionTreeRegressor?

A2. No, this plot is not specifical for DecisionTreeRegressor. If you notice that in my explanation I haven't made any assumption on the model!

Q3. Is the graph incorrect?

A3. No, the graph is not wrong. We speak of the general case of what we are expecting on an average. If you were to draw a graph only for a particular/current instance of the model running you can have Train MAE above Test MAE.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Your welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Test MAE of a model can be lower than Train MAE when it falls under below cases:

1. It is possible when you have not sampled the data or split the test train data perfectly.
2. It is possible when your test data is small and its not a good representative of train data, then there may or may not be a case when for that test data it behaves good and gives low error.
3. There can be a case when you use regularization and your train data move away from overfitting i.e. increased train error but generalizing good on test data i.e. low train error.

Answer (score 1):

Training error is generally lower or equal to test error. As test error is the generalization error for the model, it should be slightly more than the training error; but if the training error << test error, it can be due to the variance of the data or the model overfitting.